# Trigger custom form control validation on @Input change

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple custom form control with one input:

```
const NGX_HELLO_VALUE_ACCESSOR = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => HelloComponent),
    multi: true
};

const NGX_HELLO_VALIDATORS = {
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => HelloComponent),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    template: `<p>Value in custom form control: {{value}}</p>`,
    providers: [NGX_HELLO_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NGX_HELLO_VALIDATORS]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnChanges, ControlValueAccessor, Validator  {

    @Input() maxLength: number;

    value: string;
    onChangeCb: (_: any) => void = () => { };
    onTouchedCb: () => void = () => { };

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        //trigger validation
    }

    writeValue(value: any): void {
        this.value = value;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChangeCb = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouchedCb = fn;
    }

    validate(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors {
        if(this.value && this.value.length > this.maxLength) {
            return {
                tooLong: this.maxLength
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

which works fine. Whenever value changes, angular calls validate and the control is validated. The question is how to run validation when the `@Input maxLength` is changed?

I have created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmghd2) example to play around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    //trigger validation
    this.onChangeCb(this.value);
  }
```

do the trick, it seems angular rerun validation on value change.

[Forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzxszt?file=app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, it does revalidate the control, unfortunately calling `onChangeCb` sets the dirty flag on the form control. Any ideas how to prevent that?

Comment: No, since it seems that you can't access the formControl through the controlValueAccessor. But maybe you can trigger the onChangeCb only if a value is already set, ( then already dirty )

Answer (score 0):

There's a callback provided by the `Validator` interface for this exact case with [registerOnValidatorChange](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validator#registerOnValidatorChange).